# Is there a math textbook full of real-life problems which a student is supposed to model by a function which he or she creates on its own?

Tags: functions, education, book-recommendation

To motivate students in school to learn math functions, I wonder if there is some textbook full of problems which student is supposed to find a function which model this problem. Ideally, the textbook would also give the answer on how to get the solution right. I have found two such examples of the type of excercises I'm looking for here: https://socratic.org/questions/how-can-functions-be-used-to-solve-real-world-situations . But I would like more of these excercises and I can't find any colection of those on the internet. Do you have any tips on websites or textbooks?

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1, upvoted to compensate.

Comment: A quick Google search for "modeling with functions textbook" gave several results for textbooks and also [this](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Precalculus/Book%3A_Trigonometry_(Sundstrom_and_Schlicker)/02%3A_Graphs_of_the_Trigonometric_Functions/2.03%3A_Applications_and_Modeling_with_Sinusoidal_Functions) lovely webpage with lots of exercises.